# ie 10 thinking mobile version when expanded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

For some reason ie 10 the bane of all hell of browsers is thinking bootstrap nav bar is already a mobile version. How can this be when on a desktop pc the orignal bootstrap.com works grand.

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Managers</a></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Employees <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">View Employees</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Access Rights Templates</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update Authorisation</a></li>        

            </ul>
          </li>


          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Orginisation <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Leave Request List</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">eForms Teamplates</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Organisational Chart</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">User Lincenses</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>

             <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Application <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Application Parameters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Audit Trail</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Leave Request Configuration</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sickness Absence Configuration</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Triggered eForms Configuration</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>




        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> My Tasks</a></li>    


            <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Login</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
```

Does anybody have an idea as to why ??

Comment: 1) Confirm the browser mode (standards mode? compat mode? quirks mode?). 2) Use the F12 dev tools to inspect the CSS that is being applied; compare the results in IE and other browsers to see what is different. 3) Provide a JSFiddle example that demonstrates the issue. 4) Stop ranting about IE being the bane of hell: as you say, it works fine on Bootstrap's site, so it's clearly not IE that's at fault here. Ranting and blaming the tools just makes it harder for yourself to look beyond that and find the problem.

Comment: I wish i mark you as answered some reason my browser had put its self into internet exploere 7 standard document mode ?? How can that happen I have been using repsonsive site to test brwosers befoe could this do it can you add a proper answer and ill mark yours as correct ;-)

Comment: sure, I'll post an answer  :)  hold on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the browser mode -- is it in standards mode? compat mode? quirks mode?

If it's anything other than standards mode, then you've found the problem.

Solutions:

- To avoid it going into Quirks mode, make sure you have a valid DOCTYPE at the top of your HTML code:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  ```
- To avoid it going into Compatibility mode, make sure you have the X-UA-Compatible meta tag in your code, and set to tell IE to go into standards mode:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  ```

  Note that IE has config options which can tell it to default to compatibility mode, particularly when browsing local intranet sites. This often catches out developers who are using their own PC to test a site. The above line should solve this issue, it wouldn't normally happen for users accessing your site remotely over the internet, but it's good to make sure anyway.

  You might want to check that config setting on your PC anyway though, and switch it off, in case it catches you out again in the future.

Comment: Thank budy i appreciate that would been looking at that